# Random coordinates generator

Tags: python, numpy, random, coordinates

I want to generate random coordinates for spheres in a box geometry. I'm using while loop and i have 2 condition. First one is the distance of coordinates. General distance formula was used so that the coordinates do not overlap. Second one is the porosity. When porosity is less than 0.45 generating should stop. My code is working correctly but when i reduce porosity condition less than 0.80 the algorithm stucks. It cannot reach that porosity even after hours.  How can I improve it to generate coordinates faster? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
#dist = math.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2-y1)**2) + ((z2-z1)**2))
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 0.04       # x border.
B = 0.04       # y border.
C = 0.125      # z border.
V_total = A*B*C # volume
r = 0.006       # min distance of spheres.
radius = 0.003  # radius of spheres.
wall_distance = 0.003

Porosity = 1.0
coordinates = np.array([])
while Porosity >= 0.90:
    # coordinates
    x = random.uniform(wall_distance, A-wall_distance)
    y = random.uniform(wall_distance, B-wall_distance)
    z = random.uniform(wall_distance, C-wall_distance)
    coord1 = (x,y,z)
    if coordinates.shape[0] == 0: # add first one without condition
        coordinates = np.array([coord1])
    else:
        coordinates = np.vstack((coordinates, coord1))
    # seperate x,y,z and convert list for control
    d_x = coordinates[:,0]
    x = d_x.tolist()
    d_y = coordinates[:,1]
    y = d_y.tolist()
    d_z = coordinates[:,2]
    z = d_z.tolist()
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(j+1, len(z)):
            dist = math.sqrt(((x[j]-x[k])**2) + ((y[j]-y[k])**2) + ((z[j]-z[k])**2))
            if dist <= r:
                coordinates = coordinates[:-1, :] # if distance is less than r, remove last coordinate
    # check porosity
    V_spheres = (4/3) * (np.pi) * (radius**3) * len(coordinates)
    V_void = V_total - V_spheres
    Porosity = V_void / V_total

print("Porosity: {}".format(Porosity))
print("Number of spheres: {}".format(len(coordinates)))
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([0, A])
ax.set_ylim([0, B])
ax.set_zlim([0, C])
ax.set_title('Coordinates for spheres')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
p = ax.scatter(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1], coordinates[:,2])
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

Comment: First, why not move the ```(4/3) * (np.pi) * (radius**3)``` part of V_spheres calculation outside of the loop? It's value is always the same.

Comment: Are you sure you remove the correct coordinates? You remove the last while scanning coordinates in the middle. This seems odd.

Comment: Low-hanging fruit: instead of comparing the distances with r, just compare the squares of the distances with r2=r*r. Same results of comparisons, and that will save you the cost of computing all these square roots.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can do to improve your performance here. See my modified code below, with explanations

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 0.04       # x border.
B = 0.04       # y border.
C = 0.125      # z border.
V_total = A*B*C # volume
r = 0.006    # min distance of spheres.
radius = 0.003  # radius of spheres.
wall_distance = 0.003

Porosity = 1.0
coordinates = np.empty((0,3)) # initialize array with correct shape
while Porosity >= 0.70:
    # coordinates
    x = random.uniform(wall_distance, A-wall_distance)
    y = random.uniform(wall_distance, B-wall_distance)
    z = random.uniform(wall_distance, C-wall_distance)
    is_invalid = (True in [
                            math.sqrt(((x - coordinates[i_coor,0])**2) + 
                                      ((y - coordinates[i_coor,1])**2) + 
                                      ((z - coordinates[i_coor,2])**2)) <= r
                            for i_coor in range(coordinates.shape[0]) ])
    if not is_invalid:
        coordinates = np.append(coordinates,[[x,y,z]], axis = 0)
    else:
        continue
    V_spheres = (4/3) * (np.pi) * (radius**3) * len(coordinates)
    V_void = V_total - V_spheres
    Porosity = V_void / V_total
    print(f"placed coord {len(coordinates)}, por = {Porosity}")

print("Porosity: {}".format(Porosity))
print("Number of spheres: {}".format(len(coordinates)))
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([0, A])
ax.set_ylim([0, B])
ax.set_zlim([0, C])
ax.set_title('Coordinates for spheres')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
p = ax.scatter(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1], coordinates[:,2])
np.savetxt('out.csv', coordinates)
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

the main thing I changed is this double for loop

```
for j in range(len(y)):
    for k in range(j+1, len(z)):
        dist = math.sqrt(((x[j]-x[k])**2) + ((y[j]-y[k])**2) + ((z[j]-z[k])**2))
```

This was checking every pair of points for overlap EACH TIME YOU ADD A SINGLE POINT. That took unnecessarily long. By only checking if the new point intersects with the old points, you reduce your runtime from O(n^3) to O(n^2). I was able to pretty quickly run this with 0.5 perosity.

Comment: thanks for your help and kind reply. This [link](https://ibb.co/ZKvDZF4) is my code with 0.90 porosity and as you see spheres are just touch each other and this  [link](https://ibb.co/NKWJMQ3) is your correction with 0.90 porosity same as other code but spheres are inside other spheres. Any suggestion?

Comment: Thats my bad. I had a typo: instead of checking if `distance > r` I was checking if `distance > radius`. see the updated code for the fix.

Comment: I already fixed it but unfortunately still same result.

Comment: Dang, really? How do you generate that image?

Comment: I generate that spheres with SALOME, an open source program. But you can see in python plot some coordinates are too close each other.

Comment: dang it, I was overzealous with my parenthesis, which created a bug that made it seem way faster than it was. See the updated code. It will be faster than your original, but still pretty slow. I will think about this and see if I can find any other speed improvements.